# Error in Java when i try create new Files for JFlex and Cup

Tags: java

i have this, I'm using cup and jflex and i have a problem when i run the proyect. I'm trying create new class for a Files .cup and .Jflex

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String ruta = "C:/Users/Franklin Garcia/Desktop/Proyecto Compi/Pro/src/pro/Lexema.flex";
    String rutaS[] = {"-parser", "Parseador", "C:/Users/Franklin Garcia/Desktop/Proyecto Compi/Pro/src/pro/Parseador.cup"};
    generar(ruta, rutaS);
}

public static void generar(String ruta, String[] rutaS) throws IOException, Exception {
    File archivo;
    archivo = new File(ruta);
    JFlex.Main.generate(archivo);
    java_cup.Main.main(rutaS);

    Path rutasym = Paths.get("C:/Users/Franklin Garcia/Desktop/Proyecto Compi/Pro/src/pro/sym.java");
    if (Files.exists(rutasym)) {
        Files.delete(rutasym);
    }
    Files.move(
            Paths.get("C:/Users/Franklin Garcia/Desktop/Proyecto Compi/Pro/sym.java"),
            Paths.get("C:/Users/Franklin Garcia/Desktop/Proyecto Compi/Pro/src/pro/sym.java")
    );
    Path rutaSin = Paths.get("C:/Users/Franklin Garcia/Desktop/Proyecto Compi/Pro/src/pro/Parseador.java");
    if (Files.exists(rutaSin)) {
        Files.delete(rutaSin);
    }
    Files.move(
            Paths.get("C:/Users/Franklin Garcia/Desktop/Proyecto Compi/Pro/Parseador.java"),
            Paths.get("C:/Users/Franklin Garcia/Desktop/Proyecto Compi/Pro/src/pro/Parseador.java")
    );
}
```

The error is there

```
C:\Users\Franklin Garcia\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 100
```

BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)